# Rails server returns 500 internal server error but still posts to database

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax, error-handling

Although I've been pouring through similar questions for a few days, I haven't found anything that has helped. I must not be understanding something quite right. I'm attempting to modify Michael Hartl's tutorial to use modals and ajax in a rails 5 app. All is well until I try to do a password reset from a sent email link and I'm not sure if if I'm doing something wrong or if it's related to gmail/sendgrid wrappers.

I open the modals by replacing the html.erb files with js.erb for each appropriate action, then use jquery to render the forms in the modal body via partials. Works great for everything except the reset link. In the case of the reset link, though, it won't fire an edit.js.erb action which, I'm assuming (perhaps incorrectly), is because the link is looking for html and can't be modified because of potential security issues (and rightly so). The result was not being able to open the modal containing the password reset form when the reset link was clicked. The only way I could get around this was to put my jquery in an edit.html.erb file and wrap it in script tags.

Once I was able to get the modal to open when clicking the reset link, the form appears, the form submission errors are displayed when appropriate and the new password data is posted to the database as expected but ... I'm getting a 500 error from the server and nothing gets redirected. According to the headers the request is made with ajax, will accept json and the response header shows json as the content-type. Yeah, I'm a newbie, so I'm probably missing something that's clear as vodka to someone out there so apologies in advance. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

password_resets_controller.rb

```
 def update
      respond_to do |format|
        if params[:user][:password].empty?
          @user.errors.add(:password, "can\'t be empty")
          format.json { render json: @user.errors.full_messages, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        elsif @user.update_attributes(user_params)
          format.json { head :no_content }
          format.js 
          log_in @user
          @user.update_attribute(:rest_digest, nil)
          flash[:info] = "Your password has been updated."
          redirect_to @user
        else
          format.json { render json: @user.errors.full_messages, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
```

_edit.form.html

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: password_reset_path(params[:id]), data: { type: :json } , remote: true, id: "pw-reset-form") do |f| %>  

        <div class="alert info-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %>      
        </div>

      <%= hidden_field_tag :email, @user.email %>    
      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: 'Password', class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: 'Password', class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.submit "Update Your Password", class: "btn btn-primary", remote: true  %>
    <% end %>
```

edit.html.erb

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#dialog h3').html("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></i> Password Reset");
$('.modal-body').html('<%= j render("password_resets/edit_form") %>');
$('#dialog').modal("show");
$('#dialog').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
      $('.first_input').focus()
  })
</script>
```

user_mailer/password_reset.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Reset Password", edit_password_reset_url(@user.reset_token, email: @user.email)%>
```

Routes

```
 password_resets POST   /password_resets(.:format)              password_resets#create
     new_password_reset GET    /password_resets/new(.:format)          password_resets#new
    edit_password_reset GET    /password_resets/:id/edit(.:format)     password_resets#edit
         password_reset PATCH  /password_resets/:id(.:format)          password_resets#update
                        PUT    /password_resets/:id(.:format)          password_resets#update
```

Request Header

```
Host: xxxxxxxxx.herokuapp.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://xxxxxxxxx.herokuapp.com/password_resets/WZX92Z-z9OI7EhwWxSfbSg/edit?email=xxxxxx%40gmail.com
X-CSRF-Token: PkTwBobw+9x2y83hLS+QSz8AUhthAYDdUCYjXnryDQ5Ecbr9bDgAmFQ57TtOxHx6/iwerZDX1WLdgxhKP09vw==
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Length: 150
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Response Header

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 46
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 21 Apr 2017 02:11:49 GMT
Server: Cowboy
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
Via: 1.1 vegur
x-request-id: 7b6cbb63-7d7b-4e14-9612-079633ba014f
x-runtime: 0.187740
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to be about as simple as it gets. I didn't make the user an instance variable in the controller for the login. Changing login user to login @user fixed the problem and I feel like a moron for missing it. I managed to learn a lot about CORs, HTTP and the browser dev tools, though, so it wasn't a total loss but the big take away was setting "config.consider_all_requests_local" to true in the production environment. Once I could see the stack trace the problem was identified immediately. I'll be sure to set it to false before the project goes live but, man, wish I would have stumbled across that idea a couple of days ago. Oh well, live and learn. Thanks to anyone that may have put some thought into fixing such a rookie mistake!